# Cannot find node module in rails stimulus controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, npm, webpacker

I have a problem with importing an npm package that I have created into my rails application.

I'm unsure if the problem is in the way I have created the node package or with the rails app.

The package is very simple -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/test-release-stuff

Now when I'm trying to import it into rails (I install it vie yarn and then see it's in the node modules) and I try to import it into my stimulus controller it tells me that it can't find the module. The error literally says:

`Error: Cannot find module 'test-release'stuff'`

How I'm importing the module?

I'm doing `import foo from 'test-release-stuff'`

One thing to note is that when I tried that in a simple react todo app it was imported without any issues.

I have a feeling that it might be something with the webpacker config in my rails app (below is the config) or that it might be something with the node packaga `packgage.json` file, there might be something incorrect there.

```js
const { webpackConfig, merge } = require('@rails/webpacker');
const { BundleAnalyzerPlugin } = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer');
const plugins = [];

if (process.env.ANALYZE === 'true') {
  plugins.push(new BundleAnalyzerPlugin());
}

const customConfig = {
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.css'],
  },
  plugins: plugins,
};

module.exports = merge(webpackConfig, customConfig);
```

then in the production/development/test files I have something like this:

```js
process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production';

const webpackConfig = require('./base');

module.exports = webpackConfig;
```

It's a rails 6 project.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out it was neither rails app fault or the node package fault.

I'm running the project inside the container. Although I installed once the previous version of that node package, when updating it, the changes were not properly reflected inside the container - I assume at some point the actual `yarn` command was not firing or that there was some caching involved.

After properly bringing the containers down, running `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose up` the changes were reflected and I can use the node package.